# php Restricting function call to certain class

Tags: php, function, class, call, restrict

I have a class named db.php..... and I have the following method in it.

```
function query($sql){
   return mysql_query($sql);
}
```

I want that only this class can use

> mysql_query

but others can't. And others can only use by calling the

> $db->query

function of this class.

Is it possible?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) `mysql_query` is deprecated and shouldn't be used for new code (use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) instead). 2) you cannot prevent any class anywhere to use built-in PHP functions.

Comment: Perfect answer from @this.lau_

Comment: Very odd requirement. There is most likely a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure this can be achieved in an indirect way. You can rename the function and then call it again if you want:

```
rename_function('mysql_query', 'mysql_query_old' );

function mysql_query(){
  //do whatever
  //pass the call to original method if needed.
  $args = func_get_args();
  if (count($args) === 2)
    return mysql_query_old($args[0], $args[1]);
  else
    return mysql_query_old($args[0]);
}
```

To restrict it to a certain class only, you could just check the calling class:

```
$trace = debug_backtrace()[1];
$class = $trace['class'];
```

Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for more info:

Comment: Interesting. If it's possible to install that PECL extension on the server it can definitively do the trick if called from a system-wide `auto_prepend_file` directive.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, function disabling in PHP is an all or nothing setting:

- You can make the extension not load at all.
- You can ban the function with [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions), which is `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` thus a system-wide setting.

I don't think there's nothing as fine-grained as you ask. Whatever reason you have to write new code with the legacy mysql extension, you'll have to find another solution.